# Heroku Deployment Issue: Chromedriver Buildpack Fails with 'End-of-central-directory signature not found' Error

Tags: python, heroku, deployment, selenium-chromedriver, buildpack

I'm trying to deploy my application on Heroku, and I'm using a combination of buildpacks that include Chromedriver and Google Chrome for a web scraping task. The specific buildpacks that I'm using are https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome and https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-chromedriver.

The application builds fine locally, but when I try to deploy it on Heroku, I'm running into issues. The log messages from the deployment process show that the buildpack is trying to download the Chromedriver zip file but fails with the error message "End-of-central-directory signature not found.". This error typically indicates that the zip file is either corrupted or incomplete.

I've tried updating the Chromedriver version by setting the CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION to LATEST in Heroku's app settings, but it hasn't helped. I have also attempted to use other buildpacks but I'm facing similar issues.

I'm seeking help to resolve this issue, as it is preventing me from deploying my application on Heroku. Is there a known issue with the buildpack or Chromedriver's zip file? Or is there something else I could be missing that's causing this issue? Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

I have been attempting to deploy a Python application on Heroku that requires Chromedriver. To accommodate this, I have added the Chromedriver buildpack to my Heroku app settings. The buildpack is supposed to fetch the appropriate Chromedriver version during the deployment process.

I expected the deployment to proceed smoothly and the Chromedriver to be correctly installed and configured for my app. However, during the build process, I keep encountering an error stating 'End-of-central-directory signature not found'. This error suggests that there's an issue with the Chromedriver .zip file that's being fetched and unzipped.

I tried specifying a Chromedriver version manually by setting the CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION config var in Heroku. I also attempted to use the 'LATEST' version. Despite these attempts, the issue persists, preventing successful deployment of my application.